# How to pass value of a button into a function when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, arguments

So I'm trying to create a quiz for a class of mine. I've created an array of objects to hold my questions, answers, and what the correct answer is. I'm using a forEach to generate buttons for each "answer" option at the specified index. I've added and onClick event to attempt to pass the value of the button into a function but I cannot seem to figure out what's the best way to go about doing this. I've included some of my code below to hopefully help.

```
var answers = quiz[index].answers;
answers.forEach(function(element) {
    var optionButton = document.createElement("button");
    optionButton.innerHTML = element;
    optionButton.className = "btn";
    optionButton.setAttribute("option-answer", element)
    optionButton.setAttribute("onClick", "verifyAnswer()")
    questionTitle.appendChild(optionButton);
})
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the argument in your function call. here i use arrow function:

```
optionButton.addEventListener("click", () => {verifyAnswer(element)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making an onClick attribute, you could use an event listener to do additional actions when the button is clicked:

```
optionButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   verifyAnswer(currentIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the info using dataset and then recover it in the EventListener

```js
const answers=["option 1","option 2","option 3"];

answers.forEach(function(element) {
    let optionButton = document.createElement("button");
    optionButton.innerHTML = element;
    optionButton.className = "btn";
    //Add data info
    optionButton.dataset.answer=element;
    optionButton.addEventListener("click", verifyAnswer); 
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(optionButton);
})

function verifyAnswer(event){
    clickedElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
  //getting info in the element
    alert(clickedElement.dataset.answer);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Or if your answer data is the same as the text inside de button you can also use this

```
function verifyWithText(event){
    clickedElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    alert(clickedElement.innerHTML);
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the answer index when creating a button, either via a `data-` attribute or directly in the function call.

```
var answers = quiz[index].answers;
answers.forEach(function(element, currentIndex) {
    var optionButton = document.createElement("button");
    optionButton.innerHTML = element;
    optionButton.className = "btn";
    optionButton.setAttribute("option-answer", element)
    optionButton.setAttribute("onClick", "verifyAnswer(" + currentIndex + ")")
    questionTitle.appendChild(optionButton);
})
```

And then, in your function call, you can retrieve the answer using a simple accessor.

```
function verifyAnswer(index) {
    const answer = answers[index]
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with passing argument in your verifyAnswer function

```
"verifyAnswer("+element+")"
```

where "element" is argument that you want to provide it can be anything.

The other way is with listener

```
optionButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    verifyAnswer(element);
});
```